# Density function of transformation /marginal distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, density-function

**1. Density function of random variable transformation**

Given $X$ a real valued random variable with a density function $f_X$.
Let $g$ be a continuous function.

Does this imply, that the random variable $g(X)$ has a density function?
Or do I need more assumptions, for example that $g$ has an inverse function?

**2. Density function of marginal distribution**

Let $\lambda(dx,dy)$ be a Radon measure with a density function and $D$ is compact. 
Does this imply, that the marginal distribution $\lambda(dx)=\int_D \lambda(dx,dy)dy$ has a density function too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $g$ is a cosntant then  $g(X)$ does not have a density. Even if you assume that $g$ has an inverse $g(X)$ need not have a density. For example if $X$ has uniform distribution  and $g$ is  a striclty increasing singular function then $g(X)$ does not have a density.

For the second part the answer is YES. $m(A)=0$ implies $m_2(A\times \mathbb R)=0$ where $m_2$ is two dimensional Lebesgue measure. This implies $\lambda (A \times \mathbb R)=0$ so the first marginal of $\lambda$  has an absolutely continuous distribution.

Comment: Thank you, that helps!